# Read text file into array of objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to convert the data in my text file into an array of objects, here is my data in text file:

```
DOCNO   NETAMOUNT   IREF1   IREF2   DOCDT
001 30000   50  100 6/7/2020
2   40000   40  90  6/7/2020
```

Here is my code as for now:

```
  reader.onload = (ev)=>{
        const data = reader.result;
        var txtData = data.toString()
        console.log(data,"txt data")
        var lines = txtData.split(' ');
        for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
            console.log(lines[line]);
        }
    
     };
    
     reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

I want to convert into a format like this:

**0: {DOCNO: "001", NETAMOUNT: "30000", IREF1: "50", IREF2: "100", DOCDT: "6/7/20"}**

**1: {DOCNO: "2", NETAMOUNT: "40000", IREF1: "40", IREF2: "90", DOCDT: "6/7/20"}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to split the data by new line. After that split each line by spaces to get the words. At last map all the data to the right heading with [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const fakeFile = `
  DOCNO   NETAMOUNT   IREF1   IREF2   DOCDT
  001 30000   50  100 6/7/2020
  2   40000   40  90  6/7/2020
`;

// Split data by newline character
const lines = fakeFile.trim().split(/\n/g);

// Split data by spaces (one or more)
const wordsPerLine = lines.map(line => line.trim().split(/\s+/g));

// First line are the headings
const headings = wordsPerLine.shift();

// Combine lines with heading
const result = wordsPerLine.reduce((all, line) => {
  const obj = {};
  
  line.forEach((word, index) => {
    obj[headings[index]] = word;
  });
  
  all.push(obj);
  
  return all;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but i am getting some extra empty indexes. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @UsamaTariq Sure, can you update your snippet with what you've tried? Please also include the output of your `txtData` variable so i know how the data looks that you are trying to parse.

Comment: @UsamaTariq I also added some [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) functions to my snippet, maybe this will help remove leftover spaces which can cause empty indexes.